# After selecting an option in a dropdown, a value will be shown in an input. Jquery with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I just want to know, how can I show the input value after selecting an option in a drop down? I am currently appending the value of my option tag. I just need someone to talk to about it.

```
$(document).on('click', '#promo_modal', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

var get_id = $(this).data('poid');
//console.log(get_id);
$('#add_modal').modal('show');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'promo_select_name.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
        var promoName = '';
       $.each(result,function(index, value){
       promoName += '<option>'+value.promo_name+'</option>';
      });
      $('#select_promo').append(promoName);
    }
  });
```

After selecting my promo_name, the promo_price which I will place in my input will be shown after selecting an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

*Following is your ajax Function*

Just add new attr to your `<option>` as shown below

```
$(document).on('click', '#promo_modal', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

var get_id = $(this).data('poid');
//console.log(get_id);
$('#add_modal').modal('show');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'promo_select_name.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
        var promoName = '';
       $.each(result,function(index, value){
       promoName += '<option price="'+value.promo_price+'">'+value.promo_name+'</option>';
      });
      $('#select_promo').append(promoName);
    }
  });
```

Now On the change event of your dropdown call following Function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('change','#ddlChangeTest',function(){
   $('#txtSelectedValue').val($("#ddlChangeTest option:selected").attr('price'))
   });
```

**See Following Example**

```js
   $(document).on('change','#ddlChangeTest',function(){
   $('#txtSelectedValue').val($("#ddlChangeTest option:selected").attr('price'))
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><select id="ddlChangeTest">
<option price="500 $">Option 1</option>
<option price="2400 $">Option 2</option>
<option price="200 $">Option 3</option>
<option price="1000 $">Option 4</option>
<option price="21000 $">Option 5</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="txtSelectedValue" />
```

Comment: Thank you for following my post all through out. I already figure it out how can I work with my logic with the help of your idea. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can add new attr to `<option>` as **promo_price** and then call change event on dropdown & then send ajax request by promo_id to get all detail of particular promo & then feel the textbox

Comment: How can I message you privately? I want to ask more question with regards in using jquery and ajax.

Answer (score 0):

As per the description mentioned in the post:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("dropdown_selector").change(function(){
  var selectedValue = $("dropdown_selector option:selected").val();
  alert("You have selected the value - " + selectedValue);
});
```

Note that dropdown_selector is the class or ID of that particular element in that HTML.

Comment: It can be possible if I'll place it inside my success function in my Ajax call? Because the input value of my option is dependent on my table value.

Answer (score 0):

You can Implement it without ajax by using Jquery `change` Event

**Try Following**

```js
   $(document).on('change','#ddlChangeTest',function(){
   $('#txtSelectedValue').val($("#ddlChangeTest option:selected"). val())
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlChangeTest">
<option value="Selected is Option 1">Option 1</option>
<option value="Selected is Option 2">Option 2</option>
<option value="Selected is Option 3">Option 3</option>
<option value="Selected is Option 4">Option 4</option>
<option value="Selected is Option 5">Option 5</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="txtSelectedValue" />
```

Comment: I want to implement it with regards to my table value, like for example, my promo name is listed as an option in my select and each promo(option) has a promo price which is dependent on my table values. This is my reason why I am using Ajax call.

Comment: This is my current code in my problem. I will edit my post.

Comment: what is the Exact problem

Comment: what u want to do in ajax success

Comment: What I want to do in my ajax success is show the list of promos that I currently have, and If I select an option in my drop down the promo price will be shown in my input text. My current code is already showing the data value of my option.

Comment: Check New answare which I posted